# "no body provided" response when POSTing to a minimal endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, endpoint, .net-6.0

I'm experimenting with converting some simple controller methods to using endpoint routing on the latest RC of aspnet core 6. The controller works fine, and it looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(NewUserRequest newUser)
{
    /* do stuff with newUser */
    /* return CreatedAtRoute(...); */
}
```

I've tried converting to using `IEndpointRouteBuilder`, like so:

```
endpoints.MapPost("/api/user/test",
    (NewUserRequest request) =>
    {
        /* same thing as controller method */
    });

// prints error to the log:
// Implicit body inferred for parameter "request" but no body was provided. Did you mean to use a Service instead?
```

I'm using the exact same test request (through Postman, usually), so I know it's not the client's problem. What's more, if I just take an `HttpRequest` parameter, I can read the body into a json blob.

```
endpoints.MapPost("api/user/test2",
    async (HttpRequest request) =>
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.BodyReader.AsStream()))
        {
            var body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

            /* body is valid json here */
        }
    });
```

I'm really at a loss here, especially since it works in some cases, but not when I'm binding a type to one of the minimal endpoints.

Comment: If I create a minimal app with `dotnet new web` and use `app.MapPost("/api/user/test",(NewUserRequest request) =>` it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used is available in [Minimal APIs first introduced in ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/#c-10-improvements). At that time it wasn't possible to bind to specific objects yet. It's not related to Endpoint routing which was added in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

If you create a new "empty" web app with `dotnet new web` you get:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.Run();
```

This is using endpoint routing through the new [WebApplication class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-6.0). To add the POST endpoint you can use :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.MapPost("/api/user/test",(NewUserRequest request) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.Name);
        return request;
        /* same thing as controller method */
    });

app.Run();

class NewUserRequest
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Additional classes and methods must be defined at the end of the file.

Testing this with `curl` :

```
curl -X POST https://localhost:7153/api/user/test -d '{ "Name":"A"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v
```

Logs `A` in the service's console and returns

```
{"name":"A"}%
```

to the client.

The reason you get this error :

> Implicit body inferred for parameter "request" but no body was provided. Did you mean to use a Service instead?

Is that in ASP.NET Core 6 Preview 6 it became possible to [inject services without using the [FromServices] attribute](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-6/#inject-services-into-minimal-apis-without-fromservices-attribute). In the following code, the DbContext is injected:

```
app.MapGet("/todos", async (TodoDbContext db) =>
{
    return await db.Todos.ToListAsync();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, examples like that are what made me decide to attempt using endpoint routing instead of a traditional controller-based approach. I just can't figure out why the endpoint doesn't see a request body if I'm trying to bind a parameter. Since I've been making this change in a larger project, I assume there's some configuration that just isn't compatible with this approach, but I don't know what it might be. Something seems to be reading the json body, which is emptying the stream and preventing the binding code from binding to it.

Comment: @moswald the point is that these are different features. This isn't just endpoint routing, it's endpoint routing on a minimal API using the WebApplication class instead of the endpoint builder. The methods *are* different. In ASP.NET Core 5 the only acceptable parameter was HttpContext. You can still use that.

Comment: @moswald you'll have to come up with an example using the minimum possible code that reproduces the problem, and an executable request, preferably using `curl` so others can easily reproduce the issue. It may be caused by something else in the application or an actual bug. Or perhaps all this "magic" confuses the compiler so it can't decide whether you asked for a service or DTO. Or perhaps the body doesn't have enough information for the runtime to decide